# Keras MLP classifier not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, data-science

I have a data like this
[image]

[image]

there are 29 column ,out of which I have to predict **winPlacePerc**(extreme end of dataframe) which is between ***1***(high perc) to **0**(low perc)

Out of **29** column **25** are **numerical** data 3 are ID(**object**) 1 is **categorical**

I dropped all the **Id column**(since they're all unique) and also encoded the **categorical**(matchType) data into **one hot encoding**

After doing all this I am left with 41 column(after one hot)

[image: after one hot encoded]

This is how i am creating data

```
X = df.drop(columns=['winPlacePerc'])
#creating a dataframe with only the target column
y = df[['winPlacePerc']]
```

Now my X have 40 column and this is my label data looks like

```
> y.head()

winPlacePerc
0   0.4444
1   0.6400
2   0.7755
3   0.1667
4   0.1875
```

I also happen to have very large amount of data like 400k data ,so for testing purpose I am training on fraction of that,doing that using sckit

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.997, random_state=32)
```

which gives almost 13k data for training

For model I'm using **Keras sequential model**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras import optimizers

n_cols = X_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=50,
          validation_split=0.2,
          batch_size=20)
```

Since my y-label data is between 0 & 1 ,I'm using **sigmoid** layer as my **output layer**

this is training & validation loss & accuracy plot

[image]
[image]

I also tried to convert label into **binary** using **step** function and **binary cross entropy** loss function

after that y-label data looks like

```
> y.head()

winPlacePerc
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
```

and changing loss function

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

this method was more worse than previous

as you can see its not learning after certain epoch,and this also happens even if  I am taking all data rather than fraction of it

after this did not work I also used **dropout** and tried **adding more layer**,but nothing works here

Now my question ,what I am doing wrong here is it wrong layer or in data how can I improve upon this?

Comment: I believe your loss function could be the problem. Try as example the mean squared error loss.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out,I actually converted my whole label data into binary 0 & 1 using step function for that puprose I was using binary cross entropy,now I'll experiment with mean squared loss on original label data

Comment: Try adding more layers, normalize the numerical columns to -1, 1, try playing with the learning rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear things out - this is a Regression problem so using accuracy doesn't really makes sense, because you will never be able to predict the exact value of 0.23124.

First of all you **certainly** want to normalise your values (not the one hot encoded) before passing it to the network. Try using a [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) as a start.

Second, I would recommend changing the activation function in the output layer - try with `linear` and as a loss `mean_squared_error` should be fine.

In order to validate you model *"accuracy"* plot the predicted together with the actual - this should give you a chance of validating the results visually. However, that being said your loss already looks quite decent.

Check [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-which-loss-and-activation-functions-should-i-use-ac02f1c56aa8), should give you a good grasp of what (activation & loss functions) and when to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

n_cols = X_train.shape[1]
ss = StandardScaler()
X_train = ss.fit_transform(X_train)

model = Sequential()    
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=50,
          validation_split=0.2,
          batch_size=20)
```

- Normalize data
- Add more depth to your network
- Make the last layer linear

**Accuracy** is not a good metric for regression. Let's see an example

```
predictions: [0.9999999, 2.0000001, 3.000001]
ground Truth: [1, 2, 3]

Accuracy = No:of Correct / Total => 0 /3 = 0
```

Accuracy is `0`, but the predictions are pretty close to the ground truth. On the other hand, MSE will be very low pointing that the deviation of the predictions from the ground truth is very less.

Comment: Adding MSE a second time (as a metric), although not wrong, is redundant and does not offer anything really. A word of why accuracy is meaningless here would be useful.